# Is creating a new model by passing it params secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a comment model. I am creating a new instance of that model by passing it params from my view to the comment controller. Here is the comment controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
    @comment = Comment.create(:user_id  => current_user.id,
                             :issue_id => params[:issue_id],
                             :content  => params[:content])
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  end
end
```

Here is how I am passing the params in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Test Comment", comments_path(:issue_id => @issue.id,
                                          :content  => "HeLLO"),
                            method: :create %>
```

my question is - is this secure? What prevents someone from changing the params[:issue_id] and commenting on another issue? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Does your model `Comments` perform any authorization checks in its [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)? Can your model be extended to do the authorizations?

Comment: no, it does not. I couldn't think of any validations to add that would protect against a user trying to change the parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, there are better ways

at first we look to your controller. to store the referrer and redirect back to it makes no sense (at least you should NOT save this in a session) rails can do this with the key :back.

at second you dont need to make a varaible with the @ because you dont use the created object. and also you dont need to save the restult. just do

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Comment.create(:user=>current_user, :issue_id=>params[:issue_id],:content=> params[:content])
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

**++ edit**

actually a better way would to to it like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    current_user.comments.create(issue_id: params[:issue_id], content: params[:content])
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

just use rails associations

**-- edit**

and as you think, YES we can change the issue_id and write comments to any issue i want. so if you want to protect from this you have do do a helper before you crate a comment (its just an example)

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    issue = Issue.find(params[:issue_id]
    if issue.is_locked? || current_user.cant_write_at_issue(issue)
      return redirect_to :back, :notice=>"You dont have Privilegs"
    end
    issue.comments.create :user=>current_user, :content=>params[:content])
    redirect_to :back :notice=>"Comment was created successfully"
  end
end
```

is_locked and cant_write_at_issue you need to define in your models. this is just a way how to protect something.

so now we can change the issue ID but you look if the user has access for doing this :-)

Comment: these are great suggestions, thank you. the only question i have is what would is_locked? and cant_write_at_issue look like? all users have the ability to write to all issues, so i'm not sure when an issue would be locked or user can't write to an issue.

Comment: If all users have the ability to write to all issues, what's the problem? Your OP said "what's to stop them commenting on another issue?" - but you've just said that that's application functionality anyway... ?:-/

Comment: when they comment all issues, then you should not worry if someone can change the ID :)

class Issue
  def is_locked?
    locked
  end
end

make a field in the issue (boolean type), named locked. default 0. then you can set it to 1 (true) and the issue is locked and nobody can comment it. also you can have a look on can_can gem, which is very easy for abilities.